# Cocos2d tiled map - AttributeError

Tags: python, pycharm, cocos2d-x

Hello I'm developing a game with cocos2d in python. I am trying load a tiled map, but i have problems with it.

1-Large time of loading a tmx file.

2-Atribute error while loading the tiled map.

My code:

```
class Level(Scene):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        cha = Character()
        bg = load_tmx("maps/space_map_2.tmx")["space"]
        character_layer = ScrollingManager()
        character_layer.add(bg)
        character_layer.add(cha)
        self.add(character_layer)
```

How can i reduce the loading time?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***/PycharmProjects/smashking/Main.py", line 74, in <module>
    escena_2 = Level()
  File "***/PycharmProjects/smashking/Levels.py", line 13, in __init__
    character_layer.add(bg)
  File "***/PycharmProjects/course/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cocos/layer/scrolling.py", line 295, in add
    self.set_focus(self.fx, self.fy, force=True)
  File "***/PycharmProjects/course/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cocos/layer/scrolling.py", line 373, in set_focus
    return self.force_focus(fx, fy)
  File "***/PycharmProjects/course/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cocos/layer/scrolling.py", line 481, in force_focus
    layer.set_view(childs_scroll_x, childs_scroll_y, w, h,
AttributeError: 'TileSet' object has no attribute 'set_view'
```

It's crashes when : character_layer.add(bg)